# Using SASS & to target a second class of a parent

Tags: css, sass

Here is my code:

```
.grid {

    > li {

        // li styles

        .text & {

            // new li styles if .grid also has a class of .text
        }
    }
}
```

This is wrong, it seems to only work if I target something higher than `.grid`, but I want to be able to target `.grid.text li {}` so I can change the `li` styles based on if the .grid has an extra class, not depending on what `.grid` lives inside. Is this possible?

I'm trying to avoid doing this:

```
.grid {

    > li {

        // li styles
    }

    &.text {

        li {

            // new li styles
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are avoiding the second answer? To answer your question in the title, did you consider using the selector combo :not(:first)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using the `@at-root` [directive](http://sassbreak.com/getting-back-to-our-roots/) while mantaining the rules nested

e.g. this snippet

```
.grid {
    > li {
        color: #fff;

        @at-root {
          .text#{&}  {
              color: #000;
          }
        }

    }
}
```

on `SASS >= 3.3` compiles into

```
.grid > li {
  color: #fff;
}
.text.grid > li {
  color: #000;
}
```

---